# Sitecore 7.1 Upgrade - System.Xml.XmlException while installing update package

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, sitecore, sitecore7

I am trying to upgrade Sitecore from 7.0(rev. 130424) to Sitecore 7.1(rev. 130926) and whenever I try to install the update package in the update installation wizard. It is getting stuck at some point everytime and below is the log exception that I see when it happens.

```
2376 15:41:17 ERROR Attempted to load invalid xml.
Exception: System.Xml.XmlException
Message: The 'r' start tag on line 1 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'd'. Line 1, position 230.
Source: System.Xml
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
   at Sitecore.Xml.XmlUtil.LoadXml(String xml)

2376 15:41:17 ERROR First 200 characters: <r>  <r id="{4B77BB29-C937-4620-A6CC-A14B1A38DE8A}" par="Id=RenderView&amp;Path=%2fsitecore%2fshell%2fclient%2fSpeak%2fContent%2fDocumentation%2fExamples%2fChildRenderer.cshtml" uid="{AF0DDE68-3A6B-43
2376 15:41:17 ERROR Call stack:    at Sitecore.Xml.XmlUtil.LoadXml(String xml)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField.LoadData()
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField..ctor(Field innerField)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.FieldType.GetField(Field field)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.FieldTypeManager.GetField(Field field, String runtimeValue)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.FieldTypeManager.GetField(Field field)
   at Sitecore.Links.ItemLinks.AddLinks(Field field, List`1 links, ItemLinkState linkState)
   at Sitecore.Links.ItemLinks.GetLinks(ItemLinkState linkState, Boolean allVersions, Boolean includeStandardValuesLinks)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.UpdateItemVersionReferences(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.ItemEventHandler.OnItemSaved(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.DataEngine_ItemSaved(Object sender, ExecutedEventArgs`1 e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseExecuted()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Executed()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
   at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.ItemFieldChangedProcessor.Worker.UpdateField(Field field, ChangeEntry entry)
   at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.ItemFieldChangedProcessor.Worker.UpdateField(Field field, ChangeEntry entry, CommandInstallerContext context)
   at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.ItemFieldChangedProcessor.Process(String commandKey, Item versionedItem, Field field, ChangeEntry valueEntry, ICommand command, CommandInstallerContext context, Worker worker)
   at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.ItemFieldChangedProcessor.Process(String commandKey, Item versionedItem, Field field, ChangeEntry valueEntry, ICommand command, CommandInstallerContext context)
   at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.AddItemCommandInstaller.ItemInstaller.UpdateSharedFields(String addCommandKey, Item sitecoreItem, SyncItem item, CommandInstallerContext context)
   at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.AddItemCommandInstaller.ItemInstaller.DoInstall(AddItemCommand addItemCommand, PackageEntry entry, CommandInstallerContext commandContext)
   at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.AddItemCommandInstaller.DoInstall(ICommand cmd, PackageEntry entry, CommandInstallerContext commandContext)
   at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.BaseItemCommandInstaller.Put(PackageEntry entry)
   at Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Put(PackageEntry entry)
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Framework.EntryBuilder.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Update.Installer.DiffInstaller.InstallPackage(String path, InstallMode mode, ILog installationProcessLogger, IList`1 entries, String rollbackPackagePath, Boolean& hasPostAction, String& historyPath)
   at Sitecore.Update.UpdateHelper.Install(PackageInstallationInfo info, ILog installationProcessLogger, String& historyPath)
   at Sitecore.Update.InstallUpdatePackage.Install()
   at Sitecore.Update.InstallUpdatePackage.InstallPackage(MetadataView view)
   at Sitecore.Update.InstallUpdatePackage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.sitecore_admin_wizard_installupdatepackage_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

I dont see any errors in when I analyze the package but after I try to install the update this exception gets logged.

Has anyone else faced this issue while trying to update? Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't come across this issue before but it looks like the `__renderings` field on an item has become corrupted.

You should be able to tell which item as the Update installation wizard will trace through all the items it changes and prints them out on the screen- it will be the last item changed.

Once you've identified the item, find it (by guid) and view the layout section on the standard fields of the item. Switch on raw values in the top ribbon and find the issue with the xml in the field.

Once corrected, try re-running the update wizard again to see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Yeah that might be the case. The update got stuck in the middle when I tried it first time, I guess some item got corrupted that time. I tried to update again and again without restoring back everything to Sitecore 7.0 so It was causing the issue. Finally, I restored back everything and tried again and it worked!:)